# Loading WebMap using ArcGIS API for JavaScript

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-portal

I am attempting a very basic script that loads a Portal WebMap using the Esri JS API. Here is the error message I am getting:

```
(index):146 [esri.WebMap] #load() Failed to load web map 
l
details:
error: l
details:
getHeader: V=>ya.headers.get(V)
httpStatus: 400
messageCode: "CONT_0001"
messages: []
raw: {code: 400, messageCode: 'CONT_0001', message: 'Item does not exist or is inaccessible.', details: Array(0)}
requestOptions: {authMode: 'auto', body: null, cacheBust: false, method: 'auto', query: {…}, …}
ssl: false
subCode: undefined
url: "https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/items/c1127b4c1e3e4ab9bd3005192f6e6731"
[[Prototype]]: Object
message: "Item does not exist or is inaccessible."
name: "request:server"
[[Prototype]]: c
[[Prototype]]: Object
message: "Failed to load portal item"
name: "webmap:load-portal-item"
[[Prototype]]: c
```

Here is my JS script:

```
require(["esri/config","esri/views/MapView", "esri/WebMap"], 
  (esriConfig, MapView, WebMap) => {

  var esriConfig = {
    portalUrl: "https://domain/portal/home/",
  };

  const webmap = new WebMap({
    portalItem: {
      // autocasts as new PortalItem()
      id: "c1127b4c1e3e4ab9bd3005192f6e6731"
    }
  });

  const view = new MapView({
    map: webmap,
    container: "viewDiv"
  });
});
```

Here is my HTML script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>Testing</title>
  <style>
      #viewDiv {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
  </style>
  <link 
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.24/esri/themes/dark/main.css"
  />

</head>
<body>
  <div id="viewDiv"></div>
  <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.24/"></script>
  <script src="js/test_main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **'Item does not exist or is inaccessible.'** 
It's trying to access a webmap which doesn't seem to exist (see e.g. at https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=c1127b4c1e3e4ab9bd3005192f6e6731 ).  Are you using ArcGIS Online or Enterprise for this webmap?  Is it a public web map?

Comment: I'm using Enterprise for the webmap and it's shared publicly. It seems to be directing me to argis.com instead of taking on my Portal domain...

Comment: Does the network traffic show any requests to your enterprise? Maybe with some errors that makes it default back to ArcGIS Online?

Answer (score 1):

There are two way to specify the portalURL. Does it work if you change it from using the global esriConfig variable and instead do:

```
esriConfig.portalUrl = "https://domain/portal/";
```

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-config.html

Comment: I found out that adding the /home to the url was messing things up....